# Entity Framework - Return null value anyway when NullReferenceException occur

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception

Sometimes, when I try to lookup insurance name, if it is not found then I want my InsuranceName variable to have null value.    But I always get NullReferenceException. I can get around it by putting into series of if statements checking for null, is there anyway to do it in one line?

```
string InsuranceName = db.Medicares.FirstOrDefault(p => p.MedicareId = 2).Insurances.FirstOrDefault(p => p.InsuranceId = 1).Name;
```

Comment: By using `FirstOrDefault`, you are encouraging a return of NULL if not found, and then by dereferencing it (`.Insurance`) you will get a NRE.

Comment: Create your own extension

Answer (score 1):

```
var medicare = db.Medicares.Include(m => m.Insurances).FirstOrDefault(p => p.MedicareId == 2);

string InsuranceName = medicare == null ? null : medicare.Insurances.FirstOrDefault(p => p.InsuranceId == 1).Name;
```

Comment: No reason to run the query `db.Medicares.FirstOrDefault(p => p.MedicareId == 2)` twice, just run it and save the result.

Comment: I don't like to run it twice like that either. Would you please help by giving me an example.

Comment: I have updated the example for only querying once. Also does the eager loading include so that another query isn't fired off when you enumerate `Insurances` object.